# Join two tables based on ranking skipping one if criteria not met

Tags: sql, join, hive, rank

Good Day,

I am trying to join two tables that have been ranked based on specific criteria.  I would like to join these two tables based on the ranking if another criteria is met as well.  The tables is not always one for one, which is why the criteria based on rank is needed.  The two tables look as follows:

```
Table 1
sta_chng    sta_rnk
9/13/2021   1
9/12/2021   2
9/11/2021   3
9/1/2021    4
9/1/2021    5
8/28/2021   6
8/22/2021   7
3/6/2020    8

Table 2
prev_sta    prev_rnk
9/14/2021   1
9/13/2021   2
9/11/2021   3
9/2/2021    4
8/28/2021   5
8/23/2021   6
8/20/2021   7
```

I need to join the two tables by looking at the rank then comparing the dates to ensure the t2.prev_sta >= t1.sta_chng.   If the next prev_rnk date occurs before sta_chng then it should skip that row.

So based on the two tables above my expected results would be:

```
sta_chng    sta_rnk prev_sta    prev_rnk
9/13/2021   1   9/14/2021   1
9/12/2021   2   9/13/2021   2
9/11/2021   3   9/11/2021   3
9/1/2021    4   9/2/2021    4
9/1/2021    5       
8/28/2021   6   8/28/2021   5
8/22/2021   7   8/23/2021   6
3/6/2020    8   8/20/2021   7
```

So as you can see the first 4 rows are fine as the prev_sta is on the same day or after sta_chng.  sta_rank of 5 from table 1 does not match bc prev_rnk 5 on T2 occurs before it, which means it does not belong to that record. so it needs to be matched to the next one that meets that criteria.

Comment: I'm not sure I do understand your issue, but I think you could join in a little backwards. I mean select * from t1 left join (select t2.prev_sta, t2.prev_rnk, min(t1.sta_rnk) over (partition by t2.prev_sta, t2.prev_rnk) as min_rnk from t2 inner join t1 on t1.sta_chng <= t2.prev_sta and t1.sta_rnk >= t2.prev_rnk group by t2.prev_sta, t2.prev_rnk) tt on t1.sta_rnk = tt.min_rnk.
A little complicated, but nothing simplier comes to mind right now. Depends on the database engine a little too.

Comment: My issue is I only want one record from each.  I have tried joining on the date like I would normally, but by the time I get sta_rnk = 8, it matches to all 7 because the prev_Sta date is after the sta_chng date. I am trying to understand if there is a way to "eliminate" a row once joined, so it can't be joined to again.

Comment: Have you tried my query? It should filter out one row of t1 per one row of t2 using the partition by function and join the rows you want to t1. Partition by works the same for Oracle, SQLite and MySQL (MariaDb) so it should be ok.